# Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Tags: swift

What am I doing incorrectly with this statement?
currentRow is a NSIndexPath

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row && currentRow?.row == 5 {
        return  300
    }
    return 70
```

The error I get is:

> Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Comment: You can't say `return  300` but `return true` or `return false`. 300 is an `Integer` value.

Comment: @CeceXX you can return 300. Swift handles it as CGFloat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check, if your currentRow and indexPath are both `5` you can't use an if-statement like that. Change it to:

```
 if indexPath.row == currentRow?.row  && currentRow == 5 {
```

or:

```
 if indexPath.row == 5  && currentRow?.row == 5 {
```

If you want to check if `indexPath` is `nil` check if the indexPath is `0`

```
if indexPath.row != 0 && currentRow?.row == 5 {
```

Comment: Thanks Christian! That's what I get for copying and pasting code from other answers here on so :)

Comment: I'm just curious. Did you try to check if the indexPath.row is also 5, or did you want to check, if the indexPath.row is nil?

Comment: wanted to check if nil, my bad

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are trying to check a non-optional `indexPath.row` for being set.

If you would like to check `indexPath.row` for zero, add an explicit check:

```
if indexPath.row != 0 && currentRow?.row == 5 {
    return  300
}
```

Unlike Objective-C, which lets you do `nil` and zero checks without an explicit condition, Swift expects an explicit condition, or performs the check using `BooleanType` protocol implemented by optional types.