# Inline if statement mutating inout parameter in a void return closure, weird error (Error: type 'Int1' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType')

Tags: swift, closures

I've run into a somewhat weird (compile time) error that I cannot make any sense out of. The error is given for the following snippet:

```
/* error: type 'Int1' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType' */
let closure1 : (inout foo: Int) -> () = {
    foo -> () in
    (foo<0 ? (foo = -1) : (foo = 1))
}
```

> Error: type 'Int1' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Note that Int**1** is not a typo here.

**Question 1:** Why am I not allowed to use a single inline if statement (with result `'()'`) as the implicit return type of a void return closure?

**Question 2:** Out of curiosity, what is the `Int1` type? (Curiously enough the same error message, `Int1 ...` is given even if modifying the closure above to operate on different types in a similar manner).

**Why is this of interest for me?** I have a few closures that I would like to use in the anonymous form similar of `closure1Anon` below, but due to this error I can't.

Details and my own (non-fruitful) investigation into the matter follow below.

---

As described above, the error is prompted when---within a void return closure---using a single inline if statement which includes assignments to an `inout` parameter.

We can verify that result of an inline statement is the empty tuple *value*, `()`, consider e.g.:

```
var foo = -4
print((foo<0 ? (foo = -1) : (foo = 1)).dynamicType) // ()
print(foo)                                          // -1
```

... so it should be OK to use as return statement for a void return closure (see e.g. the assignment-followed-by-return example `closure4` below).

Below follows the erroneous closure (`closure1`, `closure1Explicit`, `closure1Anon`) as well as five very similar/associated closures that work fine (`closure2` through `closure7`).

```
/* error: type 'Int1' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType' */
let closure1 : (inout foo: Int) -> () = {
    foo -> () in
    (foo<0 ? (foo = -1) : (foo = 1))
}

/* same error */
let closure1Explicit : (inout foo: Int) -> () = {
    foo -> () in
    return (foo<0 ? (foo = -1) : (foo = 1))
}

let closure1Anon : (inout foo: Int) -> () = { ($0<0 ? ($0 = -1) : ($0 = 1)) }
```

Ok:

```
/* The following are all OK */
let closure2 : (inout foo: Int) -> () = {
    (inout foo: Int) -> () in
    (foo<0 ? (foo = -1) : (foo = 1))
} // thanks @MartinR

let closure3 : (inout foo: Int) -> () = {
    foo -> () in
    let _ = (foo<3 ? (foo = 1) : (foo = 2))
}

let closure4 : (inout foo: Int) -> () = {
    foo -> () in
    (foo<3 ? (foo = 1) : (foo = 2))
    return ()
}

let closure5 : (inout foo: Int) -> () = {
    foo -> () in
    let bar = (foo<3 ? (foo = 1) : (foo = 2))
    return bar
}

/* Error must be related to inout as the two
   following closures works fine */
let closure6 : () -> () = {
    () -> () in
    var a = 0
    return (a<0 ? (a = -1) : (a = 1))
}

var globalVar = 1
let closure7 : () -> () = {
    () -> () in
    (globalVar<0 ? (globalVar = -1) : (globalVar = 1))
}
```

I can't for the world figure out why `closure1`/`closure1Explicit`/`closure1Anon` above yields this error. Possibly someone can shed some light on this for me?

---

Final note: the following seemingly similar SO thread seems non-relevant in this case:

- [Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613532/type-int-does-not-conform-to-protocol-booleantype)

---

I'm using Swift 2.1.1 and Xcode 7.2.1.

Comment: I believe `Int1` is actually `Builtin.Int1` and comes from the Swift internal type representations linked to LLVM. *(I accidentally deleted my previous similar comment, sorry for the double notification...)*

Comment: I've found what I was thinking about:  stdlib/public/core https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Bool.swift uses Builtin.Int1 to create the Bool datatype. I believe we shouldn't see Int1 in an error message.

Comment: @EricD. Thanks, that answers my 2nd question, at least. I'll dig into that source code and see if we can at least find out what goes wrong (some boolean init?) Possibly something I should flag as a bug?

Comment: `closure1` compiles if you replace `foo -> () in` inside the closure by `(inout foo: Int) -> () in`. I don't why that is necessary in closure1 but not in closure2, 3, ...

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I'll add that top the top of the list of working associated closures. (Wont solve, however, the anon. closure case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Adding this thin answer to close the no-longer-relevant question)*

The bug described in the question above is no longer present in Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3) nor in the Swift 3.0-dev at [IBM Sandbox](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/); so the issue seems to have been fixed in with the release of Swift 2.2.