# Why can't I use .reduce() in a one-liner Swift closure with a variadic, anonymous argument?

Tags: swift

The first closure works. However, as soon as I take out the dummy assignment, the closure stops working (addUpClosureRedFlagged). Anyone knows why?

```
let addUpClosureWorking: (Int ...) -> Int = {
  let dummy = "Anything"  // Comment out and wait for the error...
  return $0.reduce(0, combine: +)
}

let addUpClosureRedFlagged: (Int ...) -> Int = {
  return $0.reduce(0, combine: +)   // Should work, but doesn't!
}


addUpClosureWorking(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // 15
```

Answer (score 2):

As of current Swift (2.1), the type inference of closures can behave a bit strange when containing only a single line, see e.g. [this somewhat related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184847/inline-if-statement-mutating-inout-parameter-in-a-void-return-closure-weird-err); expecting explicit inclusion of the function type signature within the closure.

This (compiler) "bug"/closure limitation is present (at least) for variadiac as well as `inout` arguments:

```
// variadiac argument example
let fooErr1: (Int ...) -> Int = {
    return $0.reduce(0, combine: +)
} 
// or: let fooErr1: (Int ...) -> Int = { $0.reduce(0, combine: +) }
   /*  error: cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Int' 
              to specified type '(Int...) -> Int'       */

// inout argument example
let fooErr2: (inout _: Int) -> Int = {
    return $0
}
// or: let fooErr2: (inout _: Int) -> Int = { $0 } 
   /* error: cannot convert value of type '_ -> Int' 
             to specified type '(inout Int) -> Int'     */
```

This can be avoided by explicitly including the function:s type signature in the closure, or including *any* statement prior to the return statement (in so extending the closure to contain more than a single line).

```
/* Avoiding fooErr1:
   - explicitly state function type signature in closure    */
let foo: (Int ...) -> Int = {
    (bar: Int ...) -> Int in
    return bar.reduce(0, combine: +)
}

/* - include any kind of statment prior to return statement */
let foo2: (Int ...) -> Int = {
    (); return $0.reduce(0, combine: +)
}

/* Avoiding fooErr2:
   - explicitly state function type signature in closure    */
let foo3: (inout _: Int) -> Int = {
    (inout bar: Int) -> Int in 
    return bar
}

/* - include any kind of statment prior to return statement */
let foo4: (inout _: Int) -> Int = {
    (); return $0
}
```

Why? I've written "bug" above, but perhaps more of a current limitation in the type inference of closures by the compiler; as Pradeep K writes in his answer, this is most likely due to some intricacies of the Swift compiler, failing type inference in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because of some optimisations that the compiler does when working on one line closures. If you explicitly accept the closure arguments as per its type then you don't need the dummy line.

```
let addUpClosureRedFlagged: (Int ...) -> Int = {
    (arr:Int...) -> Int in
    return arr.reduce(0, combine: +)
}
```

Its more about how one line closures are handled.

For e.g. Type of this closure is () -> Int. Since its a one line closure the return value of that one line is treated as the return value of closure which is Int in this case. Since it does not take any args it is (). Hence type is ()->Int

```
let addEvens = {
    [2,4,6,8].reduce(0, combine: +)
}
```

But as soon as you add the dummy line it becomes of type () -> (), a closure that does not accept any arguments and does not return any value.

```
let addEvens = {
    let dummy = 100
    [2,4,6,8].reduce(0, combine: +)
}
```

In your case the one line closure is of type (_)->Int whereas the type is (Int...)->Int You can solve this by not explicitly defining the type of the one line closure but allowing the compiler to infer the type.

```
let addUpClosureRedFlagged = {
    (arr:Int...) -> Int in
    return arr.reduce(0, combine: +)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a compiler bug. Filed a radar?

Since all your arguments are of the same type anyway you could just as well user an `[Int]` arguments:

```
let sumArray: ([Int]) -> Int = {
    return $0.reduce(0, combine: +)
}
```

`sumArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` returns the correct result.