# How to use a variadic closure in swift?

Tags: swift, closures, variadic-functions, swift2

Is there a proper way to use a variadic parameter list in a closure in Swift?

In swift I notice that I can declare a function which takes a variadic argument list like so

```
protocol NumberType: Comparable, IntegerLiteralConvertible, IntegerArithmeticType {}
extension Int: NumberType {}

extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: NumberType {
    func satisfy(closure:(args: Generator.Element...) -> ()) {
        // Do something
        closure(args: 1, 2, 3)
    }
}
```

Which builds just fine. When I try to use the function:

```
[1, 2].satisfy { (args) in
    print (args)
}
```

Xcode manages to auto complete as I would expect, but immediately upon closing the parenthesis after args, all syntax highlighting in Xcode disappears and I see a message `"Command failed due to signal: Segmentation Fault: 11"`, which appears to just mean Xcode is super confused.

For context, I had planned on seeing if Swift could write a function which could return answers based on a variable number of parameters (mapping to the number of for loops required to get a brute force answer). It would be a simple way of testing the answer to a question such as "Given an array of Ints, find all combinations which satisfy the equation a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3" with

```
let answer = array.satisfy ({ return pow($0, 3) + pow($1, 3) == pow($2, 3) + pow($3, 3) })
```

against a more optimal solution.

"Return all the 2s" would just be

```
let answer = array.satisfy ({ return $0 == 2 })
```

A single for loop

Comment: I think you're doing it the correct way, but you've found a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Compiler limitation/bug with argument type inference for single-expression closures

I believe the source of this is a current limitation (/bug) in the compiler w.r.t. inferring the argument types in single-line closures using variadic parameters, see e.g. the following Q&A

1. [Why can't I use .reduce() in a one-liner Swift closure with a variadic, anonymous argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648174/)

A similar issue was also present for `inout` arguments in Swift 2.1 (but no longer in 2.2), as is explained in the following thread

2. [Inline if statement mutating inout parameter in a void return closure, weird error (Error: type 'Int1' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184847/)

Looking at thread 1. as well as attempting to find the described bug flagged in [Swift JIRA](https://bugs.swift.org/projects/SR), however, it seems as if the OP of thread 1. never filed a bug for this, after all. Possibly I just haven't found an existing bug report, but if none exists, one should possibly be filed.

---

### Current workarounds

Possible workarounds, until the compiler's closure argument type inference catches up, are

- Extend the closure beyond single-line body

  ```
  // ...

  [1, 2].satisfy { (args) in
      () // dummy
      print (args) // [1, 2, 3]
  }
  ```
- Or, explicitly include type of `args`, e.g.

  ```
  [1, 2].satisfy { (args: Int...) in
      print (args) // [1, 2, 3]
  }
  ```

  Note that `Generator.Element` resolves to `Int` in this example above.

---

### Current status for Swift 3.0-dev

As mentioned briefly above, curiously enough, this bug

- **inout:** is apparently no longer present in Swift 2.2 or Swift 3.0-dev for `inout` arguments, w.r.t. the issues described in [Q&A 2. as linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184847/)

  - it was possibly fixed as [bug [SR-7]](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7) was resolved (-> Swift 2.2)
  - however, seems to be regression 2.2->3.0-dev, w.r.t. type inference for `inout` arguments, as reported in [bug report [SR-892]](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-892). E.g. the following snippet works in Swift 2.2, but not in 3.0-dev (minimally modified snipper from bug report [SR-7])

    ```
    func f(inout a: Int) {}
    let g = { x in f(&x) }  // OK 2.2, crashes 3.0-dev
    ```
- **variadic:** is still present in Swift 2.2 as well as Swift 3.0-dev for variadic arguments (this thread and [Q&A 1. above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648174/)).

  - a more condensed example of the bug:

    ```
    let a: (Int...) -> () = { (args) in print(args) }         // bug: crashes
    let b: (Int...) -> () = { (args: Int...) in print(args) } // explicitly state argument type, OK
    let c: (Int...) -> () = { (args) in (); print(args) }     // extend to more than single line closure, OK
    ```

(For Swift 3.0-dev, tested using the [IBM Swift Sandbox running Swift 3.0-dev](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/).

Comment: Given the previous discussion of this limitation/bug in [Q&A 1. above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648174/), I believed a bug report had already been filed for this issue. I cannot, however, find one at Swift JIRA, so I have now filed one [here; SR-1197](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1197).

Comment: Also, makes me curious about how the implementation would handle using $0, $1, etc. in the closure since they're not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: I guess I have to take that back. Using the workaround and the IBM Swift Sandbox I see that $0 is a reference to args, not a reference to args[0]

Comment: @JuJoDi Yes, a closure with one variadic parameter will only allow one single argument (e.g. `args` or `$0`), which will be an array. Note that using anonymous arguments, e.g. `$0` instead of `args` above, will be equivalent to the bug/crash case, as we (much like the crash case) trust the compiler to infer the type of `$0` correctly. Possibly broken type inference is the source of this specific bug/crash.