# Compiler crashing when using variadic parameter in closure

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

This is the code which I was trying in playground:

```
let aVar: (Int...) -> () = {
    $0
}
```

The compiler crashes saying `The LLDB RPC server has crashed` and asks me to report a bug to apple. I even tried this:

```
let aVar: (Int...) -> () = { ints in
    ints //as soon as I write this, it crashes with the above message.
}
```

I just wanted to know if what I've written is valid code as there is no way I confirm this and if variadic parameters could be given to closures as parameters too. I am using `Xcode 8 Beta 2` .

Comment: func aVar(numbers: Int...) -> () {
    for num in numbers {
        print("\(num)")
    }
}
aVar(5,4,6,7)

Comment: That's a `func` @JoeyEtamity. I was referring to `closures`. @vacawama, currently no workaround for `shorthand` arguments then?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Swift closure docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94):

> Variadic parameters can be used if you name the variadic parameter

So in theory this should work:

```
let aVar: (x: Int...) -> () = {
    print($0)
}
```

But the compiler still crashes, even with Xcode 8, probably a bug. I don't know a workaround just yet.

EDIT: This question is a duplicate of [How to use a variadic closure in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511231/6605742).