# Swift Variadic Closures Syntax?

Tags: swift, closures, variadic-functions

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489500/how-to-use-a-variadic-closure-in-swift), but need a little additional help.

I would like to construct a Closure which takes in a variable amount of Doubles, compares them to a threshold (which is also a Double) and returns a Bool checking if ALL entries were greater than the threshold. The return type should be `(Double...) -> Bool`

Here is what I have so far:

```
func isAllAbove(lower: Double) -> (Double...) -> Bool {
    return {
        var conditions: [Bool] = []
        for i in 0...$0.count {
            conditions.append(lower < $0[i])
        }
        return !conditions.contains(false)
    }
}
```

However, the compiler complains that

> Cannot convert return expression of type '(_) -> _' to return type '(Double...) -> Bool'

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how you are using the closure here and you don't really need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify parameter type and return type in closure to helps compiler to understand what value it should take and return. Also, you have a mistake in `for` loop. The interval should be like this `0 ..< values.count`:

```
func isAllAbove(lower: Double) -> (Double...) -> Bool {
    return { (values: Double...) -> Bool in
        var conditions: [Bool] = []
        for i in 0 ..< values.count {
            conditions.append(lower < values[i])
        }
        return !conditions.contains(false)
    }
}

let allAbove = isAllAbove(lower: 2)
print(allAbove(1, 2, 3)) // false
```

Also, you can write it almost in 1 line of code:

```
let lower = 2
let isAllAbove = ![1, 2, 3].contains { $0 < lower }
print(isAllAbove1) // false
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - works like a charm! Also thanks for catching my mistake in the range; would have caused an index out of range error